# Convert List of Unequal Lengths to Uniform Lengths

Tags: r, list

I have a list where each slice is of unequal lengths. Also, the number of slices is not known in advance, but I would like to set each slice to the max size. Below is an example, where the largest length of both slices is 20. The second slice has a length of 6, so I want to convert that to a length of 20, too. Preferably, the new length is filled with NA's or NULL.

```
data <- c(1,12,2,43,1,23,6,34,1,3,4,7,9,67,5,2,1,3,4,5,6,78,9,99,100,0)
splitData <- split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data)/20))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `[` operator, which when accessed beyond the length of a vector returns `NA`. You can combine this with `lapply` as follows:

```
lapply(splitData, `[`, 1:20)
```